# AWS CDK cognito with profile picture in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I want to create autohrization with aws-cognito.
I am using CDKv2, and try to achieve the following workflow:

User registers with cogninto, the request contains a profile picture. This profile-picture should be uploaded to a s3 bucket, if the registration was successfully.

I have read and tried a lot (e.g. using a lambda to achieve that), but somehow it did not worked as I would expect it.

What I want:
1.) Register using cognito (in later point using the js-sdk in a frontend as counterpart)

2.) While registering I want to add a profile picture, which gets stored in an S3 bucket. The best would be, that the `profilePicture` field would then be the link to the item in the s3-bucket (or something else, if there is a better way)

I tried to solve this by a `preSignup` lambda which is a trigger on the user pool:

```py
def handler(event, context):
    profile_picture = event['request']['userAttributes']['picture']

    file_type = profile_picture.filename.split('.')[-1].lower()

    content_type = {
        'png': 'image/png',
        'jpeg': 'image/jpeg',
    }[file_type]

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.upload_fileobj(
        profile_picture,
        'my-bucket',
        f'profile-pictures/{event["userName"]}',
        ExtraArgs={'ContentType': content_type}
    )

    return event
```

But I think I surely do something wrong. I dont know how I really can send a picture (e.g. as base64 or something else) to cognito (e.g. with `aws cognito-idp sign-up`) to store it in the bucket inside of the lambda.

I am quite new to aws-cdk and would appreciate any help!

Comment: What didn't work?  Based on what you've told us a post login trigger is likely the best bet but it not clear what "somehow it did not work" means.

Comment: @stdunbar thank you for your answer. I updated my orginial post. Any help would be highly appreciated!